# Hibernate search hanging with large amount of entities

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, hibernate-search

I have database of geonames (more than 8 000 000) entities, which are indexed by hibernate search.

I also have users and geonames  associated with them. When I try to search for users, webapp hangs and not  responding anymore and shutting down Tomcat doesn't terminates it's Java process.

According to logs, transaction starts and doesn't finish. And what is strange: on laptop with same Postgresql version this works fine but hangs on virtualbox server with same 4 GB RAM.

Also while hanging there were enough free memory space, so the problem is not in that. What could be the reason of it?

My configuration:

```
postgresql 9.3.4
postgis 2.1.1
hibernate search 4.2
```

Laptop:

```
arch-linux x64, 
virtualbox server:
ubuntu server 12.10
```

update: I realized that it creashes on spatial sorting, but there's no same error with another entity having the same assosiations with geonames. Here's error log:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.util.collections.IntToDoubleMap.(IntToDoubleMap.java:226)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.collections.IntToDoubleMap.grow(IntToDoubleMap.java:418)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.collections.IntToDoubleMap.put(IntToDoubleMap.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.search.spatial.impl.DistanceComparator.setNextReader(DistanceComparator.java:78)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$OneComparatorNonScoringCollector.setNextReader(TopFieldCollector.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.collector.impl.MapFieldCacheCollectorImpl.setNextReader(MapFieldCacheCollectorImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.collector.impl.TwoWayTransformingFieldCacheCollector.setNextReader(TwoWayTransformingFieldCacheCollector.java:59)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.updateTopDocs(QueryHits.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.(QueryHits.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.HSQueryImpl.getQueryHits(HSQueryImpl.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.HSQueryImpl.queryEntityInfos(HSQueryImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:209)
    at ru.budetsdelano.startup.server.dao.impl.UserServiceImpl.findPerformers(UserServiceImpl.java:304)
    at ru.budetsdelano.startup.server.dao.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a2118199.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at ru.budetsdelano.startup.server.dao.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4966a48e.findPerformers()
    at ru.budetsdelano.startup.server.controller.json.JsonSearchForPerformersController.searchFreePerformers(JsonSearchForPerformersController.java:70)
    at ru.budetsdelano.startup.server.controller.json.JsonSearchForPerformersController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$edd7b285.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)

update: here is search method:
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
QueryBuilder queryBuilder =fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query spatialQuery =queryBuilder.spatial().onCoordinates("pl").within(50000, Unit.KM).ofLatitude(latitude).andLongitude(longtitude).createQuery();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query isPerformerQuery =  queryBuilder.keyword().onField("performer").matching(true).createQuery();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query nameQuery = ((!keywords.equals("") && (keywords != null))) ? queryBuilder.phrase().withSlop(10).onField("name").sentence(keywords).createQuery() : null;
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query  geonameIdQuery = geonameid != null ? queryBuilder.keyword().onField("city.geonameid").matching(geonameid).createQuery(): null ;
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query profileQuery = (profile != null)? queryBuilder.keyword().onField("profiles_string").matching(profile).createQuery() : null;
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query minimalBudgetQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField("minimal_budget").from(minimalBudget != null ? minimalBudget : 0L).to(maximumBudget != null ? maximumBudget :Long.MAX_VALUE).createQuery();
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query minimalRatingQuery = minimalRating!= null ? queryBuilder.range().onField("task_rate").from(Double.valueOf(minimalRating)).to(Double.valueOf(5)).createQuery() : null;
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query isOnlineQuery = (onlineOnly == true) ?  queryBuilder.keyword().onField("online").matching(true).createQuery() : null;
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query freeOnlyQuery = (freeOnly == true) ?  queryBuilder.keyword().onField("active_tasks_count").matching(0).createQuery() : null;
            BooleanJunction total = queryBuilder.bool().must(isPerformerQuery).must(minimalBudgetQuery).must(spatialQuery);
            if (profileQuery != null) {
               total = total.must(profileQuery);
            }
            if (nameQuery != null) {
                   total = total.must(nameQuery);
            }
            if (isOnlineQuery != null) {
                  total = total.must(isOnlineQuery);
            }
            if (freeOnlyQuery != null) {
                   total = total.must(freeOnlyQuery);
            }
            if (geonameIdQuery!=null) {
               total = total.must(geonameIdQuery);
            }
            else if (minimalRatingQuery != null) {
                total = total.must(minimalRatingQuery);
            }
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query totalQuery = total.createQuery();
            FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(totalQuery);
            //fullTextQuery.setSpatialParameters(latitude,longtitude,"place");
            if (orderType == User.OrderType.distance) {
                Sort distanceSort = new Sort(new DistanceSortField(latitude,longtitude,"pl"));
                fullTextQuery.setSort(distanceSort);
            }
            else if (orderType == User.OrderType.minimal_budget) {
                SortField sortField = new SortField("minimal_budget",SortField.LONG,reverse);
                fullTextQuery.setSort(new Sort(sortField));
            }
            else if (orderType == User.OrderType.rating) {
                SortField sortField = new SortField("task_rate",SortField.DOUBLE,reverse);
                fullTextQuery.setSort(new Sort(sortField));
            }
            fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(from);
            fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(quantity);
            return (List)fullTextQuery.list();

Comment: Post your search routine.

Comment: You'll also want to check whether it's still doing the `Postgres` query or is somewhere in `Hibernate` or other part of your Java code. You can use `PgAdmin` to see active queries on the server (among other methods).

Comment: Post your configuration + search code. Also turn on debug logging and see whether you see something there. If you can try to attach an debugger to find out where it hangs. How do you manage transactions? Manually? Via annotations? You say searching does not work, did the indexing work in this case?

Comment: I did some research and found that problem is in spatial sorting - jvm crashes with out of memory. When I've disabled sorting everything started working fine. What is strange: the same with sorting of another entity works fine and this entity has the same many to one associations as user entity with wich I have trouble.Still can't understad why....

Comment: Do you have the same JVM configuration on laptop and on virtualbox? It looks like your heap space is just too small ...

Comment: yes it's the same, and I noticed that this can be either on laptop or virtualbox) so, something wrong with code, but still can't understand what... I even removed all field, embedded indexes and so on, only latitude and longtitude annotations remained and Spatial(spatialmode = grid), but nothing changed

Comment: You just have a too small heap for the kind of data you're processing. If you can't use a larger heap, update Hibernate Search: in version 4.2 support for geospatial queries was new and experimental. If you take 4.5.1 there are many performance and memory optimisations, version 5 (not final yet) will have many more improvements.

Comment: is hibernate spatial 4.5.1 compatible with hibernate 4.2?